# Is there a way in .Net Framwork to reference an object cross AppDomains without Serialization?

Tags: c#, marshalling, appdomain, remoting, marshalbyrefobject

I am developing an addon to a commercial software which has an object that I have no control with it.  By "no control with it", I mean I can't access its source code and make it `serializable`.  It just sits in the current `AppDomain` for me to reference when my addon gets attached.

Now I want to make my addon (`dll` library) hot plug&play and to achieve that I need load my addon to a separate `AppDomain`.  I was able to do that with a dummy addon, for example, in one version, I let it `MessageBox.Show("A")`, and I can hot swap to a different version and have it `MessageBox.Show("B")`.

Now to the real battle: I need have it output `MessageBox.Show(obj.Title)` in one version and in another `MessageBox.Show(obj.Id)`.  Granted I can pass `Title` or `Id` as string, but I need do a lot more than that and want to pass the whole `obj` to my addon so I can do things with it.

Since I can't make it `serializable`, direct passing it as an argument is out of question.  I tried to create a container for it by creating a wrapper class like below:

```
[Serializable]
public class Arg : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public ObjectIHaveNoControl Obj { get; set; }
}
```

and then tried to pass it to my addon via proxy (I use `AppDomainToolkit`):

```
var proxy = Remote<Addon>.CreateProxy(addonDomain);
proxy.RemoteObject.DoSomething(new Arg() { Obj = currentDomainObject });
```

It throws the same exception saying the `obj` is not `serializable`.

Did I hit a dead-end?  I'm about to give up, then I recalled we are able to use `VSTO` or `Office Interop` to control `Excel` from another process.  So there's gonna be a way to accomplish this, isn't it?

Comment: If you are very careful, you can use StructureToPtr (creates a byte[]) and PTRToStructure (create structure from byte[]).  First the Structure has to be declared exactly the same on where ever it is used and compiled with same version of Net/Core.  The object is just byte[]. So as long as you can convert the object to byte[], send the bytes between machines, and then back to the object it is equivalent to serialize/deserialize.,

Comment: Just throwing this out there, most Json serializers can serialize pretty much anything, whether they're `Serializable` or not. There's more overhead compared to binary serialization/memory marshalling, but it's more debuggable and likely safer.

Comment: If your `Arg` is derived from `MarshalByRefObject`, then is doesn't make sense to make it serializable because it will be a remote object in a different app domain. The issue is that its members should also be either serializable or remoting-capable types. Instead of passing `ObjectIHaveNoControl` directly pass some serializable descriptor instead that contains everything to recreate `ObjectIHaveNoControl` locally.